# Sending file from objective-c to java

Tags: java, objective-c, file-upload, client-server

Problem with upload file. I'm sending file from objective-c to java;

Server side:

logger doesn't appear in tomcat.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody MessageWrapper getMessage(@RequestBody MessageWrapper msg,  @RequestParam("photo") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
logger.info("Send");
/*
    my code
*/

return msg;
}
```

Client side:

```
__block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setData:message.imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];

NSArray *toEmail = [message.to componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:toEmail, message.subject, message.content, nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"to", @"subject", @"body", nil];

NSDictionary *msgDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSString *jsonRequest = [msgDict JSONRepresentation];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setUseCookiePersistence:NO];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-type" value:@"application/json"];
[request setRequestCookies:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[self setKidCookieParams]]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setPostBody:[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:requestData]];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

it works correctly, without following lines:

```
[request setData:message.imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
and server side like  this:
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody MessageWrapper sendMessage(@RequestBody MessageWrapper msg) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Send");
    /*
        my code
    */

  return msg;
 }
```

Please, help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many times I tested it, the file is sent separately and json object is sent individually, too.
But together will not be sent. How can i perform both actions at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you mix the `@RequestBody` (which is assumed to consume the complete request body) and a `@RequestParam` (which, as it is supposed to represent file data, would be part of the request body). Having the request body consumed completely by one item and have a part of it passed in as another parameter does not work. Similar on the Objective-C side you first add a `photo` parameter to the request body and then you overwrite the complete body with `setPostBody:`.

Instead on the server side you need to declare the `MessageWrapper msg` as a separate `@RequestParam`, and hope the JSONDeserializer picks it up properly. If it does not, first use `@RequestParam String msg` and see if at least the JSON string value arrives, and then try to make the deserialization work.

Then the Objective-C part needs to be updated, too. I am not very familiar with Objective-C, but I feel it is necessary that instead of `[request setPostBody:[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:requestData]];` you need to add the JSON part as a separate parameter of this multipart-fileupload, and the request header `Content-Type` should be  `multipart/form-data`, indicating that you upload several items here.

At this SO question: [http file upload Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161657/http-file-upload-objective-c)
I found a pointer to http://cocoadev.com/wiki/HTTPFileUpload  As said over there, that page is hardly readable, but at the bottom is some code that submits data given as a dictionary "name" -> "value", where "value" can be either a string or a file, and maybe you can adapt that to your purposes. This example constructs the complete request body manually - I am not sure but I think meanwhile there are more convenient options in Objective-C.

For example I wonder if simply calling something like `[request addData:requestData forKey:@"msg"]` works, but then, no Objective-C environment here and thus not tested.

If you really want to know what is going on behind the scenes of http file upload (please do, understanding that stuff makes programming it easier), read the [RFC 1867](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867) on file upload (ignore the HTML part for now and look how the request body is put together), or for a simple example, e.g. see [here](http://www.vivtek.com/rfc1867.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work).